# how to properly allow nodejs to have a chance to run its async events in my inifinite while loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, events

Whenever I run my 'save_to_db' function at location B, it fails.

The code below shows the problem...

```
//location A

var i = 0;
while(true)
{

    i++;
    if(i == 100)
    {

//location B

        save_to_db(newUnit, 11214.1, 'TEST');
    }

}


//location C
```

The function 'save_to_db' works fine at Location A & C. But failed at Location B.

I think it is because the while loop is infinite and synchronized. Therefore it doesn't give nodejs chance to run its event loop. How can we properly give nodejs a chance to run its event loop in this case?

===================== updates ===============================

The code above is very simplied version of the code. I have a class/module called 'db_util' and it has two methods, 'save_to_db' and 'read_from_db'. I think because of these methods used 'mysql' module, they access database in an async way. But my while true loop blocks nodejs eventloop. Therefore neither methods in the while loop has a chance to be invoked.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var db_util = function()
{}

db_util.prototype = {
    save_to_db: function (neural_network, fitness, type) {
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'nodejstestdb'
        });
        connection.connect();      
        var addSql = 'INSERT INTO mytable(id, nn, type, fitness) VALUES(?,?,?,?)';
        var addSqlParams = [null, neural_network, type, fitness];
        connection.query(addSql, addSqlParams, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('[INSERT ERROR] - ', err.message);
                return;
            }                  
            console.log('INSERT ID:', result);          
        });
        connection.end();
    },


    read_from_db:function(){

        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'nodejstestdb'
        });
        connection.connect();

        var sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY fitness DESC'; 
        connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('[SELECT ERROR] - ', err.message);
                return;
            }
            console.log(result);
            var nn = result[0].nn;            
            neural_network = synaptic.Network.fromJSON(JSON.parse(nn));           
            return neural_network;
        });
        connection.end();
    }
}

module.exports = db_util;
```

================ update 2 because of the answers

```
let i = 0;
(function tick() {
    ++i;
    if (i%100 == 0) {
        save_to_db();
    }
    setTimeout(tick, 0); // Queue a callback on next(ish) event loop cycle
}());
let i = 0;
tick();
```

@T.J. Crowder, Sir thanks for your answer. But what's the difference between your above code and the code below?

```
var i = 0;

function tick() {
    ++i;
    if (i%100 == 0) {
        save_to_db();
    }
    setTimeout(tick, 0); // Queue a callback on next(ish) event loop cycle
}

tick();
```

Comment: run events, infinite loop. Choose one. They are generally incompatible. You shouldn't need an infinite loop.

Comment: when it breaks the loop

Comment: Try using `setInterval` instead of an infinite loop

Comment: @VLAZ I understand this. How do you convert infinite loop into an 'event-based structure', any typical examples?

Comment: *(I thought I posted this comment, but the evidence suggests otherwise. :-) )* What does `save_to_db` do? Does it return a promise? Do you call it more than once, or just when `i == 100`? If you call it more than once, is it a problem if those calls overlap? What is the purpose of the loop?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please could you refer to my updated post. I have questions about the way you wrote your answer.

Comment: If you state that that function call "fails", what **exactly** does that mean? Is there any error message given? What have you tried to debug that problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried to place 'save_to_db' to the 3 locations. Loc A & B are working, data successfully saved into mysql. However, when I tried at Loc B, it doesn't give me any error message. I think it is because it never allows 'connection.query()' to run, because the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As VLAZ says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56748318/how-to-properly-allow-nodejs-to-have-a-chance-to-run-its-async-events-in-my-inif#comment100054713_56748318), I wonder why you need an infinite loop, rather than just using the event loop.

> I think it is because the while loop is infinite and synchronized. Therefore it doesn't give nodejs chance to run its event loop.

Yes, you're exactly correct.

It's hard to answer this question without knowing how `save_to_db` works, but in general you have three options:

1. Use a chained series of `setTimeout` (or `setImmediate`) callbacks.

   - Variation: You do a block of the work (say, up to 100 iterations) and then use `setTimeout` to schedule the next block.
2. Use an `async` function and `await` (if `save_to_db` returns a promise, or can be modified to return a promise).
3. Use a [worker thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html), which posts a message to the main thread when it should do the `save_to_db` (then the worker thread's event loop being blocked doesn't prevent events on the main thread that `save_to_db` needs). (I probably wouldn't use a worker for this.)

---

#1 looks roughly like this:

```
let i = 0;
(function tick() {
    ++i;
    if (i == 100) {
        save_to_db();
    }
    setTimeout(tick, 0); // Queue a callback on next(ish) event loop cycle
}());
```

Note that Node.js rate-limits timers, so `setTimeout(tick, 0)` won't necessarily schedule the next call on the next event loop iteration. You might use [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args) instead, because it

> Schedules the "immediate" execution of the callback after I/O events' callbacks.

For example, this code:

```
let i = 0;
let last = Date.now();
let sum = 0;
(function tick() {
    ++i;
    sum += Date.now() - last;
    if (i < 1000) {
        last = Date.now();
        setTimeout(tick, 0);
    } else {
        console.log(`Average: ${sum / i}`);
    }
})();
```

reports an average elapsed time of 1.155ms on my Node v12.4 installation on my Linux box. The equivalent code using `setImmediate` reports an average of just 0.004ms instead.

You've said in a comment that you didn't understand how to implement doing this in "chunks." Here's an example:

```
const chunkSize = 1000; // Or whatever
let i = 0;
(function chunk() {
    const chunkEnd = i + chunkSize;
    while (i++ < chunkEnd) {
        if (/*time to save to the DB*/) {
            // Note that we don't wait for it to complete, you've said it's
            // okay not to wait and that it's okay if they overlap
            save_to_db();
        }
    }
    setImmediate(chunk, 0);
})();
```

Doing it that way, it does a chunk of work on the main thread, then yields to allow processing of any I/O callbacks that save_to_db might need, then keeps going. You could optimize it a bit to only yield back when it knows that `save_to_db` still has work to do, but that's probably overengineering it.

---

#2 looks roughly like this:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        let i = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (i == 100) {
                await save_to_db();
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle/report error
    }
})();
```

#3 I'll leave as an exercise for the reader, but I probably wouldn't use a worker for this.

Comment: I agree that it's hard to say what OP wants to do. It *seems* like they want to add 100 items to the database. Maybe sequentially. It's also possible that a `save_to_db().then(() => save_to_db()).then(save_to_db()) /* etc */` would work or can be made to work. Or maybe there is some sort of batch insert method or one can be easily made: `save_all_to_db`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for your answer. I updated the question. Please see the original post.

Comment: @wildcolor - I had an editing error in my implementation of #1, see the update. With the update, the only difference between mine and your alternative you asked about is that `tick` is added to the scope where this code occurs in yours, and not in mine (because a named function expression doesn't add the function name to the scope where it occurs, just *within* the function). Not a big difference.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the answer. I guess that's what makes me 'a new JS person' confused. Probably that's why JS is fast because these 'native features'. Brilliant answers. However, I do notice a significant performance difference between a while loop and your #1 answer. Assume the 'save_to_db' in your #1 is a console.log(i). Then I notice compare to while(true){console.log(i); } and your settimeout #1 method, the while(true) is significantly faster. Any comments? (assume we print out every 10 number, ie use i%10 ==0 rather than i==100)

Comment: @wildcolor - Yes, there's a **huge** performance difference, because yielding back to the event loop on each and every iteration introduces a **lot** of overhead. Also, Node.js may well not even schedule the timer callback on the next event loop (which is one reason I mentioned [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args), and also mentioned doing things in blocks/batches); it rate-limits timers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hi Crowder. I picked your answer as my final 'ticked' answer. However, I noticed a significant performance difference between my old while loop and your #1, even when I replace settimeout with setimmidiate. (about 4 times difference in performance :(  ) Is there another way to give nodejs a chance to save my data to DB in my whole loop, say sleep a bit every other 10s?

Comment: @wildcolor - Yes, again, yielding back to the event loop is going to involve a lot more work. If you told us what the infinite loop is for, we could probably help you get rid of it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will try to describe it see if you could help me. The loop is running a game logic with several STATES like shown here https://github.com/ssusnic/Machine-Learning-Flappy-Bird/blob/master/source/gameplay.js. In this example, the guy uses the 'Phaser' game library to help to manage/invoking different states. I simply do not need graphics rendering at all, so I don't use the library. Instead, I added the while loop to navigate these states. In the 'PLAY' state, I am training a neural_network on 100000 data.

Comment: @wildcolor - During this loop, do you need the loop to wait for `save_to_db` to finish? Can calls to `save_to_db` overlap? (You may recognize these questions... :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As long as I can execute it, it's good for me. Currently, the while(true) loop doesn't allow 'save_to_db' to run. So my data cannot be saved into mysql database..... If it can run, it doesn't matter if it is a bit delayed or overlapped.

Comment: @wildcolor - Then it sounds like you may want chunks (say, 100 loops -- or 1000, or ... --- and then `setImmediate` to allow I/O), or put the loop in a worker and have the worker post a message to the main thread to do the save (#3 above).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the answer. I get what you mean, but I do not know how to really get it done by doing chucks. Oh, do you mean use while(<1000) as a chuck, then run setimmidiate(to continue for another while <1000)? this seems to be a solution. :) :)    by the way, Is there a 'sync' version to save to db? Check my code at update 1, I think it is async version. so it doesn't get executed.

Comment: @wildcolor - I don't know the MySQL driver well, but I don't *think* it has a sync option. I've added an example of chunks above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Superb. and it works for me. Thanks a lot for keeping answering my stupid questions. I really appreciate it. You help a lot.

Comment: @wildcolor - No worries! I didn't think they were stupid. :-)